# Access a K8s service via DNS name from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a K8s cluster running with a few services in it. BEcause of K8s DNS, within the cluster services can talk to each over via HTTP request with their name as the URL (e.g `http://foo-bar-svc`). This is great because I don't need to use an IP address, which I'm assuming would change every time a pod gets redeployed.

Now I want a Cloud Function to be able to post a request to one of these service.

I've followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc#creating_a_connector) guide and successfully created a VPC Connector.
From my Cloud Function, I can make a HTTP request to a service in my K8s cluster, but only if I use an explicit IP address.

How can I instead use one of the URLS that the K8s DNS can resolve?

Comment: Are you using GKE or bare-metal k8s?

Comment: This is a pure guess.  When you use a VPC Connector, you can connect to a VPC IP ... but what then is the VPC IP of your pod?  I think you may have to setup an internal TCP/UDP load balancer.  This would then expose your pod with a VPC IP that could then be reached.  See  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing

Comment: @GoAOz I'm using GKE

Answer (score 1):

The best way to expose a k8s service with ingoing host request, is ingress.
You can define a Ingress ressource link with your service, example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 4200
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 8080
```

In this example we define a host foo.bar.com to resolve and depends of the path /foo or /bar we reroute to a service behind. Of course you can replace it by the prefixe "/*" for reroute all to one specific service path.

Please refer the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

But with this configuration you need to have a Load balancer in front and an alias to a DNS entry:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress?hl=en

And to be more resilience you can add one ingress controller (nginx,traefik....): https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/

So, the schema will be:

DNS server <-> Client resolv DNS -> LB -> Ingress Controller -> Service -> Pod -> container.

I hope it helps.

Comment: What if one didn't want to expose the cluster to an external Internet facing IP address?  My understanding of the VPC Connector is to allow calls to be made from Cloud Functions to services attached to VPC.  I think in Kubernetes speak these would be Cluster IPs.

Comment: I'm not sure I can achieve what I want here with GCP. I am trying to avoid exposing the cluster to the internet, and instead have the cloud function as the public facing entrypoint.

Comment: So you are using Cloud function to expose your k8s service, you can still use ingress ressource k8s, it is similar to a server web vhost. With ingress two Solution: If you want to use a DNS resolver server (ex: curl -X POST http://foo.bar.svc), you still need to create a DNS entry (ex: A) to your External IP address, to be private https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns. Otherwise, without a dns server entry, you still keep ingress ressource, but for each HTTP request you need pass Host in header (ex with curl: curl -H "Host: foo-bar-svc.com" http://<External-IP>/

Comment: If you have a secure and private network environment for your k8s with the ingress and cloud function method you will stay private. Morever, to be more secure you can add jwt authentication for your API, enable RBAC and role for your pod and service in your k8s....